How should I weight points for which the uncertainties are unknown in a quantile regression?
Background
I am trying to analyse a compilation of data from different experimental studies and would appreciate advice on how to think through weighting points in a quantile regression.
I am not attempting to do a classical meta-analysis. Instead, I would like to perform a quantile regression on a response $Y$ as a function of two continuous predictors $X_1$ and $X_2$ (both manipulated in experiments). My goal is to obtain the best parameter estimates of the effects of $X_1$ and $X_2$ on the ~90th quantile of $Y$ (the mean/median are not of scientific interest).
However, I only have access to mean values per treatment in some cases (not raw data) and so I believe I need to weight points. I have limited experience with weighted least squares, and none in the context of quantile regression. I understand that the typical approach in a simpler regression would be to just weight means by 1/variance. However, this isn't possible for all cases.
Questions

In studies where only means were reported, about 1/3 did not report an associated uncertainty (SD/SE/variance). How should I weight these points?
Many studies used regression designs with no replication. This is scientifically and statistically reasonable, but again: how should I weight these points?
A secondary issue for which input would be nice but not necessary: when I calculate 1/variance for all cases reporting mean values with uncertainties, I get values that differ by 2-3 orders of magnitude. I think this substantially underestimates the uncertainty in the cases with high weights, possibly because the variance is often being estimated from very few measurements.

What is the best way to address these? Are there any additional complications in the context of a quantile regression?
Probably not relevant, but additional context
Ideally, the experiments would have used regression designs and measured $Y$ across a consistent range of values of $X_1$ and $X_2$. However, the experiments vary greatly in not just the values of $X_1$ and $X_2$, but also the number of levels - some used just 1 or 2 levels of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are used.
Also, one would ideally account for variation at the study and species level. I'm ignoring these entirely here because I believe they are less important issues. But I'm happy to have this answered in the context of mixed/hierarchical models as well.

Could you explain why you think weighting would be an appropriate mechanism for addressing your underlying problem?

@whuber I thought that at least in a standard (non-quantile) regression, I could calculate the mean values in each treatment and study combination, then weight those mean values by 1/variance and use WLS to get the best parameter estimates. Assuming that logic is correct, I had hoped it could be extended to quantile regression as well. I'd be happy to be corrected on this and also to entertain other suggestions.

I don't follow that: if you "only have access to mean values," how are you obtaining estimates of upper quantiles?

@whuber I only have access to mean values for a subset of the data, perhaps 25%. So for the remainder I have the raw data and can obtain upper quantiles. But are the means in that 25% informative? I imagine it would introduce a downward bias on the 90th percentile that I am interested in, but I would think it can be. However, I'm open to the possibility that the quantile regression is best performed after omitting the means. Or that I should omit the means without uncertainties but simulate datasets from the means with uncertainties and repeat my quantile regressions across simulated datasets.

Or other approaches - I'm happy to learn what the best solution would be here.

The means are likely informative, depending on your assumptions about the conditional distribution.  At one extreme, with OLS regression and homoscedastic Normal errors, the means suffice (along with the estimated residuals SD) to estimate any quantile.  At another extreme, if it's possible the conditional distributions are arbitrarily skewed, a mean tells you virtually nothing about any percentile.  I hope this might suggest additional information you could provide to help address your question.

@whuber Thank you, I will ponder that and take a closer look at the data.
